# How to configure the timer code more efficiently?

Tags: discord.js

When using this code, the message is updated every second, and then suddenly moves slowly or quickly in every five seconds. I want to make a more stable timer. What should I do?

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Collection } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: "timer",
    async execute(message, args) {
        ggg=args.shift(1)
        let timecc = ggg*60
      const tic = await message.reply("⏳"+parseInt((timecc / 60)/60)+"h"+parseInt((timecc / 60)%60)+"m"+(timecc % 60)+"s")
      var timer = setInterval(() => {
          timecc --
          tic.edit({ content: "⏳"+parseInt((timecc / 60)/60)+"h"+parseInt((timecc / 60)%60)+"m"+(timecc % 60)+"s" })
          .catch(console.warn = () => {});
          
          if (timecc === 0) {
              clearInterval(timer);
              tic.edit({ content: "⌛"+"@everyone time out!" })
              .catch(console.warn = () => {});
              } 
}, 1000)
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be an issue relating to the Discord API.  Editing a message every second falls under API abuse. It's possible you're being ratelimited, or the API is unable to fulfill the request every second

Comment: A more viable option would be to only edit the message at a certain point in the timer's depletion. For example only edit the message once the timer is halfway done and once it has finished

Answer (score 2):

Discord limits the amount of messages any user can send (you can try this yourself by spamming messages in any channel; you should see the same 5-second-interval behavior as your bot if you do it enough).

Sadly, the only solution for this is to send messages less often.

Comment: I followed the advice, but I still have the same symptoms. I changed it to every 5 seconds, but now it's edited every 15 seconds